# Detect failed plugin load and display message

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website for a school assignment and I'm using the google reader flash plugin to play some music. When I am at home the plugin works fine, but at school it doesn't load, and I just get a blank spot where it should be. This is because the school proxy filter blocks the google server hosting the plugin.

I am wondering if there is a way to detect when the plugin is blocked and display some alternate text. Here is the code I am using:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="audioUrl=http://k006.kiwi6.com/hotlink/zhxhgz5q0z/island_of_peace.mp3" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf"  width="400" height="27" quality="best" alt="Flash plugin failed to load">  </embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this via PHP:

```
<?PHP
if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) {
   //Hide flash
}

// otherwise no proxy detected

else {
   //Display flash
}
?>
```

Just a quick solution, may not always work though. Depends if the proxy is anonymous or not